# Vue axios makes put request to wrong URL

Tags: laravel, vue.js, routes, resources, axios

so I've got this weird problem where if I make a Put request through axios in Vue, it's sending it to the wrong route.

It's part of a simple CRUD through a Laravel APIresource. Get and post work fine.

This is the form:

```
<form @submit.prevent="editType" method="post" class="mb-4">
            <label v-if="user.gender === 'man'" for="single_male">Enkel<input type="checkbox" name="type" :id="single_male" :value="types.single_male" v-model="checkedType" @change="showSaveButton = true"></label>
            <label v-if="user.gender === 'vrouw'" for="single_female">Enkel<input type="checkbox" name="type" :id="single_female" :value="types.single_female" v-model="checkedType" @change="showSaveButton = true"></label>
            <label v-if="user.gender === 'man'" for="double_male">Dubbel mannen<input type="checkbox" name="type" :id="double_male" :value="types.double_male" v-model="checkedType" @change="showSaveButton = true"></label>
            <label v-if="user.gender === 'vrouw'" for="double_female">Dubbel vrouwen<input type="checkbox" name="type" :id="double_female" :value="types.double_female" v-model="checkedType" @change="showSaveButton = true"></label>
            <label for="double_mix">Dubbel gemengd<input type="checkbox" name="type" :id="double_mix" :value="types.double_mix" v-model="checkedType" @change="showSaveButton"></label>
            <button type="submit" v-if="showSaveButton">Opslaan</button>
        </form>
```

My update function:

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user_id = auth('api')->user()->id;

        $type = Type::where('user_id' ,'=', $user_id)->first();

        $type->single_male = $request->input('single_male');
        $type->single_female = $request->input('single_female');
        $type->double_male = $request->input('double_male');
        $type->double_female = $request->input('double_female');
        $type->double_mix = $request->input('double_mix');

        $type->save();

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

my method:

```
editType() {
                let types = this.types;
                let data = {
                    single_male: this.single_male,
                    single_female: this.single_female,
                    double_male: this.double_male,
                    double_female: this.double_female,
                    double_mix: this.double_mix,
                };
                axios.put('/types/'+types.id, data)
                    .then(request => this.successfulEdit(request))
                    .catch(() => this.failed())
            },
            successfulEdit() {
                alert("Voorkeuren succesvol bijgewerkt!");
            }
```

and my route:

```
    Route::apiresource('types','TypeController');
```

When I make a put request, I can see in the Developer Tools that it tries to make the request to the current url, which of course gives a 405 method not allowed error. 
When I change the axios request to just ('/types', data), it does follow the specified route but of course gives the 405 error too since the put method requires an id. Hardcoding to e.g. '/types/4/' also leads to using the current url.

Am I missing somethng or what's wrong? Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: What's the value of `types.id`? Can you show the output of `console.log('/types/'+types.id)`?

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your help!`types.id` seems to return undefined. Console logging `types` does return the correct data, though it seems to pass it in an array (while in this case there is only one object). I think the problem lays there somewhere. Console logging `types[0].id` does return the desired id, but writing `axios.put('/types/'+types[0].id, data)` doesn't seem to work either.

Even hardcoding the id in the url isn't working.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. The `return redirect()->back();` was the culprit. Thanks y'all!

Answer (score 1):

From Laravel docs. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing

> Routes defined in the routes/api.php file are nested within a route
>   group by the  RouteServiceProvider. Within this group, the /api URI
>   prefix is automatically applied

So try to add `/api` before your current request URL like
`axios.put('/api/types/'+types.id, data)`

Comment: I've configured axios' baseURL to be /api already, so I don't have to define it again. You couldn't have known of course ;-)